# Как сверстать такую подложку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли сверстать такой блок как на картинке. Возможно ли это средствами css или проще сделать картинкой ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, используя псевдоэлемент [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

```css
 .box {
   position: relative;
   background: #999;
   height: 150px;
 }
 .box:after {
   top: 100%;
   left: 20%;
   border: solid transparent;
   content: " ";
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
   pointer-events: none;
   border-color: #999 transparent transparent transparent;
   border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
   margin-left: -15px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">box</div>
```

**Добавлено:**

Если блок и треугольник (прямоугольный) будут иметь тень, то всё-же придется делать картинкой.

При равностороннем треугольнике можно решить проблему тени с помощью `transform`. Например: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/91oL85pc/).

Comment: Может быть стоит дополнить. Если блок и треугольник будут иметь тень, то придется делать картинкой и через `css` уже не получится